# Validar si existe un registro en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando validar si existe un registro en la base de datos de mysql mediante una alerta con php pero no genera dicha alerta

```
if (isset($_POST['numExp']) && !empty($_POST['numExp'])) {


    $consulta=$PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE numExp=".$numExp);
    if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)=0) 
        { 
            echo '<script>
                    alert("ERROR AL REGISTRAR");
                    </script>'; 
        }else{

        $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO fechas_tbl (numExp, fecha) VALUES (:numExp,:fecha)");

        $sql->bindParam(':numExp',$numExp);
        $sql->bindParam(':fecha',$fecha);
        $sql->execute();

        }
```

Comment: Donde tienes declarado $numExp? ademas en el  `if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)=0)` estas asignadole cero, la comparación se hace con `==`, deberia ser `if (mysql_num_rows($consulta)==0)`

Comment: numExp es una variable que esta recibiendo por post

Comment: Igual lo intente con == pero no me arroja la alerta si no existe dicho registro

Comment: Pero dentro del `if (isset($_POST['numExp']) && !empty($_POST['numExp'])) { ` no la tienes declarada, si la declaras fuera y tiene un valor null o no tiene valor, la consulta se realizara con eso, declara $numExp dentro de ese if, `$numExp = $_POST['numExp'];`

Comment: Ademas estas usando el driver PDO o mysql para realizar las consultas? en ese codigo estas mezclando ambos.

Comment: asi es, ya loa gregue como dices, y si se esta mezclando el envio de datos esta perfecto no hay falla, pero esta condicion que me arroje alerta noesta bien, tienes algun codigo en pdo que me pueda funcionar equivalente a que no encuentre x registro?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo tu código estas combinando los drivers para la conexion a mysql, si usas PDO, debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isset($_POST['numExp']) && !empty($_POST['numExp'])) {
  $numExp = $_POST['numExp'];

  $consulta=$PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE numExp=".$numExp);
  $consulta->execute();
  $num_rows = $consulta->fetchColumn();

  if ($num_rows==0){ 
    echo '<script>
          alert("ERROR AL REGISTRAR");
          </script>'; 
  }else{
    $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO fechas_tbl (numExp, fecha) VALUES (:numExp,:fecha)");

    $sql->bindParam(':numExp',$numExp);
    $sql->bindParam(':fecha',$fecha);
    $sql->execute();

  }
}
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar mi estimado

Comment: @matteo Te sale algún nuevo error? o sigue sin llamar el script?

Comment: sigue sin llamar al script, lo cambie por un simple echo pero tampoco al parecer no entra a la condicion

Comment: realiza un print_r($consulta->execute()); para ver si esta realizando el query correctamente.

Comment: No me manda ninguna cadena, ya quite el primer if donde valida si esta vacio o no para que siempre este entrando.... ademas lleno el formulario y si envia los datos asi que la conexion esta bien.

Comment: puedes colocar la cadena de conexion PDO?

Comment: $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbregistro;charset=UTF8','root','' );

Comment: Al inicio de tu script habilita el reporte de errores, con ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL); para revisar si te esta lanzando alguna excepcion

Comment: El documento php lo tengo separado del html, por lo que solo mostrara error cuando desencadene el evento al dar click al boton donde esta enviando los datos al formulario, y sigue sin mostrar, no se que pasa, si puedo enviar registros y todo , pero no me manda ni el script ni nada por el estilo al validarlos, simplemente los agrega a la db

Answer (score 3):

Tal vez sea esto lo que te falta

```
$consulta=$PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE numExp=".$numExp);

$consulta->execute();
$result = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result){//aqui va tu script de error}
```

Answer (score 0):

posiblemente el error está en hacer

```
 if ($num_rows==0)
```

probar

```
 if ($num_rows==1)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error.");</script>';
```

Eso podría ayudarte.